# pylint.lint Run sometimes writing and closing json file, and sometimes not

Tags: pylint

Trying to write a basic script to generate pylint scores on a repository, record the pylint messages to a json file, and then subsequently read the json file for some post-processing.

This basic script works sometimes, and sometimes not.

The error seems to be related to having the json file completely written and closed from pylint.lint Run prior to attempting to read the json. Sometimes the json file is empty (0 bytes) when attempted to be read, but immediately after the code errors out, the json file is completed and contains corrects json formatted messages.

Is there some explanation / solution to this?

Here is the code:

```
import os
import json
import time
from pylint.lint import Run


def pylint_scorer(path_to_linter, fp_json) -> dict:

    results = None
    lx_scores = {}
    output_option = '--output-format=json:' + fp_json + ',colorized'

    pylint_options = [path_to_linter, output_option]
    results = Run(pylint_options, do_exit=False)

    if results is not None:
        lx_scores = {'score': round(results.linter.stats.global_note, 2),
                     'num_statements': results.linter.stats.statement,
                     'fatal': results.linter.stats.fatal,
                     'error': results.linter.stats.error,
                     'warning': results.linter.stats.warning,
                     'convention': results.linter.stats.convention,
                     'refactor': results.linter.stats.refactor,
                     'info': results.linter.stats.info}

    return lx_scores


def parse_json(f_json: str) -> list:

    ls_msg = []
    if os.path.getsize(f_json):
        with open(f_json) as f:
            ls_msg = json.load(f)
    else:
        print('Empty json file referenced, size = %d', os.path.getsize(f_json))

    return ls_msg


if __name__ == '__main__':

    path = 'C:/Users/Desktop/pylint_json_error'
    json_file = 'pylint_results.json'

    lx_pyl_score = pylint_scorer(path, json_file)
    print(lx_pyl_score)

    ls_msg_count = parse_json(json_file)
    print(ls_msg_count)
```

Here is a sample output:

```
pylint: Command line or configuration file:1: UserWarning: Specifying exception names in the overgeneral-exceptions option without module name is deprecated and support for it will be removed in pylint 3.0. Use fully qualified name (maybe 'builtins.BaseException' ?) instead.
pylint: Command line or configuration file:1: UserWarning: Specifying exception names in the overgeneral-exceptions option without module name is deprecated and support for it will be removed in pylint 3.0. Use fully qualified name (maybe 'builtins.Exception' ?) instead.
************* Module pylint_json_error.pylint_to_json
pylint_to_json.py:56:0: C0305: Trailing newlines (trailing-newlines)
pylint_to_json.py:1:0: C0114: Missing module docstring (missing-module-docstring)
pylint_to_json.py:8:0: C0116: Missing function or method docstring (missing-function-docstring)
pylint_to_json.py:30:0: C0116: Missing function or method docstring (missing-function-docstring)
pylint_to_json.py:34:47: C0103: Variable name "f" doesn't conform to snake_case naming style (invalid-name)
pylint_to_json.py:44:4: C0103: Constant name "path" doesn't conform to UPPER_CASE naming style (invalid-name)
pylint_to_json.py:45:4: C0103: Constant name "json_file" doesn't conform to UPPER_CASE naming style (invalid-name)

------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 7.59/10 (previous run: 7.24/10, +0.34)

{'score': 7.59, 'num_statements': 29, 'fatal': 0, 'error': 0, 'warning': 0, 'convention': 7, 'refactor': 0, 'info': 0}
Empty json file referenced, size = %d 0
[]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

And here is how the json file is AFTER the code fails (4 KB in this case) ...

```
[
    {
        "type": "convention",
        "module": "pylint_json_error.pylint_to_json",
        "obj": "",
        "line": 56,
        "column": 0,
        "endLine": null,
        "endColumn": null,
        "path": "pylint_to_json.py",
        "symbol": "trailing-newlines",
        "message": "Trailing newlines",
        "message-id": "C0305"
    },
    {
        "type": "convention",
        "module": "pylint_json_error.pylint_to_json",
        "obj": "",
        "line": 1,
        "column": 0,
        "endLine": null,
        "endColumn": null,
        "path": "pylint_to_json.py",
        "symbol": "missing-module-docstring",
        "message": "Missing module docstring",
        "message-id": "C0114"
    },
    {
        "type": "convention",
        "module": "pylint_json_error.pylint_to_json",
        "obj": "pylint_scorer",
        "line": 8,
        "column": 0,
 ... etc. ...
```